# How to repeat a javascript function in a php foreach with getElementByClassName?

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q16Q7.png)   Hello I want to reproduce a Javascript function for all users of an interface in PHP, I used for that getElementByClassName but despite and a loop so that the function is repeated for all users. But it does not work and the browser shows me each time a new syntax error, do you have an idea to solve this problem?

PS: I put the javascript code in the same document only to make it easier to read here

```
    <!-- user -->
        
        
       
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
   

            <div style="padding-top: 90px; padding-left: 30px;">
    <div class="user_style2">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    
      
    
    
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <p><?php echo $course['Id']; ?></p>
            <p>install_id</p>
            <p>branch_id</p>
            
        </div>
        <button onclick="hiddenButton()">Try it</button>

<div class="DIV" name="DIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>





      </div>
        </div>
          </div>
              </div>
                  </div>
                      </div>


        


</body>

<script>
 
function hiddenButton() {
      
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("DIV");

      for (i=0, i<x.length, i++)
        if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
          x[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
          x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }

      </script>

<?php
                }
                // End the foreach loop 
           ?>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div style="padding-top: 90px; padding-left: 30px;">
                    <div class="user_style2">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

                                <p>install_id</p>
                                <p>branch_id</p>
                            </div>
                            <button onclick="hiddenButton()">Try it</button>

                            <div class="DIV" name="DIV">
                                This is my DIV element.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function hiddenButton() {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("DIV");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
                if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
                    x[i].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Revised code

Comment: Please add some explanation of what caused the error and how your code fixes it instead of just dumping code. Thanks

Comment: There is a error in the for lop.I just fixed it and you are using the function in the onclick event in this case function is not been called multipletimes if you put it into the php loops.